# How to make changes to objects in the page above

Tags: c#, button, uwp, frame, navigationview

I have a `NavigationView` that loads a page into its associated frame.

On the loaded page there is a button, how can I use this button to change the properties of the `NavigationView`.

I know that to update the page in the frame is:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Window2));
```

So I thought it might be:

```
Frame.NavigationView.IsEnabled = False
```

But this isn't valid.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Define "didn't work". Didn't compile? Threw an exception? Ran but nothing happened?

Comment: Could you please clarify what happened when you said "that didn't work"? This may help solving your problem.

Comment: Sorry, as in it just isn't a valid command but I don't know the correct way to achieve it

Comment: @DSNB: Is `Window2` the "loaded page" and is the `Frame` and the `NavigationView` located in the same view/XAML file? Please post your XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set `NavigationView.IsEnabled` directly from loaded page.You can set a property in a  viewmodel to bind with the IsEnabled of navigationView.When you navigate a new page by `Frame.Navigate()`,pass the viewmodel to the new page.You can set the property to false when you click the button in the page.In this case,the navigationView will be disabled.

.xaml:

```
<NavigationView IsEnabled="{x:Bind MyViewModel.IsEnabled,Mode=OneWay}">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Item 1"></NavigationViewItem>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
</NavigationView>
```

.cs:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private bool isEnabled = false;
    public bool IsEnabled {
        get { return isEnabled; }
        set {
            isEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage: Page
{​
    public MainPage()​
    {​
        this.InitializeComponent();​
        MyViewModel = new ViewModel();
    }
    private ViewModel MyViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

When you want to navigate a new page,pass the viewmodel:

```
ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1),MyViewModel);
```

Page1.cs:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    isEnabledVM = (e.Parameter as ViewModel);
}
private ViewModel isEnabledVM { get; set; }
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    isEnabledVM.IsEnabled = false;
}
```